# Why a null pointer is not evaluated as NULL

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm using this function to parse a CSV line taking care of empty items:

```
char *strtok_new(char *string, char const *delimiter, char **context)
{
    // context unused
    static char *source = NULL;
    char *p, *ret = 0;

    if (string != NULL) source = string;
    if (source == NULL) return NULL;

    if ((p = strpbrk(source, delimiter)) != NULL) 
    {
        *p = 0;
        ret = source;
        source = ++p;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Example of use:

```
char buffer[64]; // "foo,,,,blabla"
const char delimiters[] = ",";
char *token;
char *ptr;

token = strtok_new(buffer, delimiters, &ptr);
// ...
token = strtok_new(NULL, delimiters, &ptr);
if (token == NULL)
{
  // do someting
}
```

The comparison is always false.
I added a debug `printf`:

```
Serial.printf("%s,%u,%u\n", token, strlen(token), token[0]);
```

on the test case it outputs:

> ,0,0

So we have a zero-length string, and (as expected) the first byte is 0 (aka `NULL`).
Why the `if` clause fails? Changing it to:

```
if (strlen(token) == 0)
```

leads to my expected behavior.
I'm using the Xtensa toolchain v8.4.0 for Arduino/ESP32 with `gnu++2a` flag.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72595551/null-pointer-doesnt-evaluate-to-false) question but it does not seem to apply here.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `nullptr`

Comment: `strlen(token)` -- If `token` is NULL, this statement leads to undefined behavior.  The `strlen` assumes `token` is a null-terminated string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so it's impossible to retrieve the length of an empty string? (`\0`)

Comment: @Mark You are confusing an empty string to NULL.  A NULL pointer doesn't point to anything.  `const char *ptr = "";` -- What is the value of `ptr`?  It isn't NULL.

Comment: @user12002570 changed to `if (token == nullptr)` but the behavior is the same

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm going to find a resource to study it better. But `NULL` is 0 and an empty string has 0 as first byte. I don't get my fault, sorry

Comment: This is C++ not C. So try to at least use std::string_view (instead of `char*`) for your tokenizer function. And `std::string` for your `char[64]`.

Comment: @Mark  No.  NULL does *not* mean an empty string.  Can you dereference a NULL pointer without undefined behavior?  No.  `const char *ptr = ""; cout << *ptr;` this is OK.  However, this leads to undefined behavior --  `const char *ptr = NULL; cout << *ptr;`.

Comment: *"But NULL is 0 and an empty string has 0 as first byte."* What's the difference between an empty piece of paper and a treasure map that leads to an empty chest? Both are empty.

Comment: As to NULL (or `nullptr`), they are useful if you are directly testing for NULL or `nullptr` or initializing a pointer to a default value, or returning that "something has gone wrong" if a function can't perform a task.  However they are not replacements for "empty" or "empty string".

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Not only will that clarify your question, it wall also help you to focus on the core issue.

Comment: Think of it this way: `const char *ptr = ""` you have an empty box. `const char *ptr = nullptr` you don't have a box at all.

Comment: Here is a tokenize function in C++ NOT using any pointers. https://onlinegdb.com/ddAweK09K.  C++ does not recommend "raw pointer arithmetic" (and I think you are to start understanding why). Also see
https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#probounds-bounds-safety-profile

Comment: ... and you can open an empty box to see that it's empty. Opening a non-existing box leads to the collapse of the universe.

Comment: `token==NULL` means *is there a string behind*? Which is not the same as `strlen(token)==0`, which means *is the string behind empty*?. *Empty string* != *No string*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem stems from a confusion between:

- a string
- the first character of a string

which is also a confusion between:

- a pointer to characters
- a character

Your example code is irrelevant.  Your problem can be shown as follows:

```
char* p1 = NULL; // a null pointer
char* p2 = ""; // an empty string (DEFINITELY NOT A NULL STRING)
strlen( p1 ); // undefined behavior, usually catastrophic failure
strlen( p2 ); // returns 0
int n1 = (p1 == NULL)? -1 : stlen( p1 ); // n1 receives -1
int n2 = (p2 == NULL)? -1 : stlen( p2 ); // n2 receives 0
```

A "null string" is a `char*` pointer which has received the special value `NULL` and is thus called a null pointer. A null pointer does not point to anything. Strictly speaking, "null string" is a misnomer, because it is not even a string, but we let that slide and we use the term "null string" to refer to a pointer which would be pointing to a string, if it was not `NULL`.

An ***empty string*** is a ***very non-null*** pointer which points to a character with the value of `'\0'`.  "Emptiness" is a quality of strings (and of arrays in general): a string may and may not be empty, but this has nothing to do with the pointer that points to the string.

The `'\0'` character is often called a "null character" or a "null terminator" but it has nothing to do with the `NULL` value for a pointer. The similarity between null for a pointer and null for a character is just an unfortunate historic coincidence: this character receives its name from [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), where it was called "NUL" (note the one L) long before C++ or even C came into existence. ASCII was born circa 1963; C was born circa 1973. C++ was born circa 1979.

Comment: The name of the character whose value is zero (`'\0'`) is [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), not NULL. But it's reasonable, IMO, to call it a null character (as long as that adjective is not spelled with all uppercase characters).

Comment: @j6t thanks for the note, I incorporated it into the answer.